# Sending data via socket.emit from client to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to send some data (number) from client to server via socket.emit. The problem is that server doesn't seem to receive any data because only `null` is consoled out or I am trying to get it wrong. Where might be a problem?

**client side**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages();
    socket.emit("openedConversation", { conversationId });
  }, []);
```

**server side**

```
  io.on("openedConversation", ({ conversationId }) => {
    console.log(conversationId);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
io.on("openedConversation", conversationId => {
   console.log(conversationId);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.